# Django running under python 2.7 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

According to the docs, AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports Python 2.6. I wonder if anyone has set up a custom AMI using the EBS backed 64 bit Linux AMI to run django under Python 2.7 on the beanstalk? While most aspects of a set up under 2.7 will probably be straightforward using virtualenv or changing the symlinks, I'm worried about the amazon build of mod_wsgi. I understand that depending on how mod_wsgi has been compiled there may be issues with running it in combination with Python 2.7. I also wonder if there will be any postgreSQL issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today (Nov 8, 2013), as I checked AWS support Python 2.7 AMI. Even though, documentation is still not updated properly. Please try to use eb CLI tool and then you can find the below AMI options.

```
17) 32bit Amazon Linux 2013.09 running Python 2.7
18) 64bit Amazon Linux 2013.09 running Python 2.7
```

No more hassle to use Python 2.7! :)

Answer (score 3):

This blog post seems interesting:

[Getting a Python 2.7 project running on Elastic Beanstalk](http://leetreveil.roon.io/getting-a-python-2-7-project-running-on-elastic-beanstalk)

The author also provided a sample project for testing:

https://github.com/leetreveil/elasticbeanstalk-python27

Comment: This is by far the most correct answer - following this blog post instructions, I managed to deploy an application on ElasticBeansTalk using just standard configuration options.  No custom AMI or other difficult to maintain solutions

Comment: The AWS team recommended this to me.

Answer (score 1):

To get around `mod_wsgi` limitation, you can deploy your application under your own wsgi container like uWSGI and add configuration to apache to serve as a reverse proxy for your WSGI container.

You can use container_commands to place your apache configuration files under /etc/httpd/...

Comment: Thanks, but as I note in my answer I found the whole beanstalk configuration process rather restrictive.

Answer (score -1):

In the end I built mod_wsgi using Python 2.7. The documentation was easy to follow: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

Recently, however, I switched from the Amazon Linux AMI to an official ubuntu AMI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide

It is so easy to add instances to a load balancer and connect to an RDS using an ubuntu ami I didn't see the need to persist with the Amazon Linux AMI and the beanstalk, which I found rather restrictive.

Comment: The cooooolness of beanstalk is one-click deploy feature. Run `git aws.push` your new version is in the air on all of the servers. After crafting my own solutions for this, heaving such a feature our of the box is so wonderful.

Comment: There are many advantages to use EB, as Zaar mentioned above.  The Rockalite answer is probably the best way to go for Python 2.7 and EB as of today